# Xcode 4.4 - show warnings on unused imports/includes

Tags: xcode, cocoa

Is there a way to make XCode to show warning messages on unused import and include?

Comment: I dont think this works this way, but you can try using Product -> Analyze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this directly from Xcode.

You may check «Include What You Use», which is an open-source project using Clang to detect un-necessary included headers.

http://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/

Answer (score -1):

The best way to find out which imports or includes are unnecessary is to comment them one by one and try to compile ;)

Comment: This could probably be automated with a shell script.